# Azure Function - PDF Sharp HTML to PDF - Cannot save a PDF document with no pages

Tags: .net, azure-functions, pdfsharp

I am using PDF Sharp to take HTML I give it and generate a PDF. The code below works locally but when deployed to an Azure Function and hitting from Postman it gives the error "**Cannot save a PDF document with no pages.**".

I've seen a few different articles on the PDF Sharp Forums but nothing that solved my issue.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;

public byte[] HtmlToPDF(string html)
        {
            
            try
            {
                byte[] pdfBytes;

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(
                        System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance
                    );
                    
                    // Breaks on this line
                    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
                    pdf.Save(ms);
                    pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

               return pdfBytes;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }            

        }
```

Not exactly sure why it's working locally but not deployed on an Azure Function. The HTML I am passing locally is the save as what I'm passing to the Azure Function.

Comment: I'd expect to see it break on the `pdf.Save(ms);` line. Is it Azure running on Linux or Azure on Windows? Maybe you need a FontResolver.

Comment: Azure on Windows

Comment: HTML Renderer is not part of the PDFsharp package, it is an independent project. I suspect you need a FontResolver. It could be that, without a FontResolver, no fonts can be found under Azure, and, as a result, no pages will be generated. But maybe something else is going wrong. It might help to attach a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm sure it had to do with that I uninstalled that old version and found a new one called HtmlRendererCore.PdfSharp

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, if anyone has issues in the Future trying to use this with .NET Core.
I uninstalled TheArtOfDev version and found another package called HtmlRendererCore.PdfSharp by J-Petty.

Once installed should work very similar to the old one.
https://github.com/j-petty/HtmlRendererCore